# AC RMS from half wave controlled rectifier

Tags: rectifier, practical

I have built the following circuit:
[image]

I measured the AC RMS at output as 975.8 mV:
[image]

I can't get anywhere close to that measured value when using the AC voltmeter formula below (for delay angle of 90):
[image]

I'm getting 9.67V from using the formula. I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: It looks like a full-wave rectifier to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your calculations, mistake of moving a comma 1 decimal place is quite hard to spot on. Looking at you'r formula for AC Voltmeter reading:

- V=Vs * SQRT((pi-a+0.5 sin a)/pi)

first part Vs is 2.5/SQRT(2) = 1.77V, second part clearly less than 1 (0.5 sin a<a, pi-something < pi, SQRT(something) < 1 when something < 1) so you shouldn't get anything bigger than Vs. Correct reading should be 967mV NOT 9.67V.